# Is it possible to use other variable names in Realm?

Tags: android, realm

I would like to parse a JSON object and map it to a RealmObject directly using the method `createObjectFromJson`.
My JSON is looking like that:

```
"data": {
  "default": "a string"
}
```

So I make a RealmObject class like this

```
public class Data extends RealmObject{
  private String default;
  // GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

So I can call the method

```
realm.createObjectFromJson(Data.class, json);
```

Obviously the problem here is that I cannot use the keyword `default` to name my variable.
Is there any way to annotate my variable in Realm to use an alias ?
I'm aware that I can modify my input JSON but the aim is not to do it so I can have a generic method to map my JSON to a RealmObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm does not support renaming variables, but JSON libraries like GSON and Jackson do. You should look into those instead and then use `copyToRealm` or `copyToRealmOrUpdate` instead of `createObjectFromJson`